# Cannot find references tab to change copy local in visual studio 2015

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio-2015

I have hosted my ASP.NET website for the first time on a remote hosting server provided by the hosting provider.

My SQL Connection strings works fine both on my local machine and when connected to the remote SQL server from the local machine but when I run the actual remote website I get the error:

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

I was asked to set Copy Local to True. After searching I found that this can be changed on References tab but I cannot find References tab in Visual Studio 2015. Can someone help please?

Comment: I think the reason I have been asked to set Copy Local to True so that I can then Publish my site again with Database as well. At the moment I added the database directly using upload feature provided by the hosting provider. I wonder what difference does that make?